# Is there a way to add "retry" to triggered jobs in gitlab ci?

Tags: triggers, gitlab, gitlab-ci

Triggered jobs in gitlab ci do not support 'retry' keyword (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#trigger).

Even using 'retry' in 'default' section (i.e. 'default:retry') does not seem to affect triggered jobs.

Is there a way to set retries for triggered jobs? I want to set retries for all jobs including the triggered ones.